# React JS (Admin on Rest) error when API call

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm making a API call (GET) using React js ([Admin on Rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest)).

I already check on API server when I call to localhost:5001/cites, server return cities data, but I don't know it error on client side, here is log from browser :

```
failure.js:18 Error: The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. This header is necessary for pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header?

at convertHTTPResponseToREST (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33928:28)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33966:21
```

and

```
failure.js:18 Error: The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. This header is necessary for pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header?

at convertHTTPResponseToREST (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33010:28)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33037:21
```

May someone can help ? Thanks

Comment: I think you are using any Package for pagination. 
I am not sure for back-end which technology or framework you are using. But you need to allow Content-Range in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header for back-end app(Rails, PHP or any other).

Comment: maybe it's included on Admin on Rest framework, I already add on headers, but still not work, or maybe I'm wrong on set headers, I'm newbie in react. so what do you think ?

Comment: This issue is related to backend app, you just need to allow Content-Range in header. Which framework you are using for beckend app.

Comment: I'm using Rails 5 --api, you mean it raise when backend app return data ?

Comment: yes, Its return before entering to your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Admin-on-rest needs a way to determine how many results there are in total, even if your API returns only a subset of the results - in order to build the pagination controllers. For instance, if the API returns 10 results but mentions there are 100 results in total, admin-on-rest will display 10 page links.

The `simpleRestClient` and `jsonServerRestClient` both expect to see this information in the response headers, either in `X-Total-Count`, or in `Content-Range`.

If your API doesn't include these headers, you can:

- update your API to include the total as `X-Total-Count` header, or
- write your own RESt client to grab the information about the total number of records somewhere else (e.g. in the response body)

Answer (score 0):

Update your backend API function to get X-Total-Count and set it to Response Header

Example:

```
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
  var total = Data.countAll()// your count all function
  Data.findAll({ where: condition })
    .then(data => {
      res.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Total-Count')
      res.set('X-Total-Count', total)
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving data."
      });
    });
};
```